# Configure Swagger UI + Jersey 2 with JdkHttpServerFactory

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, jersey-2.0, swagger-ui

I am attempting to set up Swagger + Swagger UI in a pre-build project which uses neither the Jersey 2 container Servlet nor the Filter configuration (with web.xml) as stated in the [official docs](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#2-hooking-up-swagger-core-in-your-application).

My main class looks like this:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("//localhost/").scheme("http").port(8080).build();
        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();

        final HttpServer httpServer = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, resourceConfig, false);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            httpServer.stop(0);
        }));
        httpServer.start();
    }

}
```

I want to use package scanning and the Swagger UI to keep track of my API. All answers i found stated you should either extend the `Application` class or use a Filter configuration with a `web.xml` file. Please give me a hint on how to add Swagger to the existing project which was given to me.

I am new to JAX-RS and a bit confused... so I ask for understanding. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to just extend the Application class in your existing one.

You can also do this operation without using any api. Just call the report with the parameters you want with REST call to your jasper server.